# Play framework as a game server

Tags: html, websocket, playframework-2.0

I want to try writing a simple game for web, using the websockets and HTML-5 technologies, and I am thinking about doing this with Play framework and Scala. However, the type of game that I want to make is one with a persistent world where things happen themselves, and not only as player action consequences, what means, that it does not fit the Play's stateless philosophy. I have tried starting a separate thread in Play application, that would act as a usual persistent gameserver with a running world, and it seems to work. How can you comment on that?

- Will I face some big problems with this approach?
- Is there a better solution and setup for that? What do ppl usually use for such things aside from standalone (non-http) game servers?
- Can you share any interesting experience considering a similar problem?

Comment: I think it will fit perfectly. Stateless in this sense does mean no state in a user session held between requests. But of course you have state, persistently in a database or transiently in a cache of stateful Akka actors. The latter being your way, IMHO ;-)

Comment: Great comment, actually would fit for the answer, especially looking at the activity))) Thanks for the encouragement, I will go for the Typesafe Stack then.

Comment: Good luck ;-) Let us know how it works out on the Google group!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not mess up **persistent** with a **"always running thread updating info"**.

Most of the time, such games just save last update time and they calculate new values based upon time elapsed between now and last update. Any web framework or technology can do that. 
Even if I am a big playframework fan/addict, I do not think the persistent argument in itself is enough.

But if you need :

- good websockets integration,
- support heavy traffic,
- massive concurrency without massive servers

then indeed, Playframework might be your choice.

Comment: I understand what you are saying - about calculating the state from the time. But there is supposed to be a big number of mutable objects and the functional approach is computationally inefficient... The whole thing will be backed up by MongoDB, but I literally mean that - "backed up" - I want to use it *only* for daily snapshots and for the case of server shutdown. I think that Play will do. I have successfully implemented a proof-of-concept solution. Now it is only the question of upbringing it.